# Are the values of function arguments read from a .dmp file reliable?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

This .dmp file was dumped by a release build. Opened with visual studio C++ (2010), in the call stack view, the values of function call arguments are strange, some values are missing while some others are inconsistent.

For example:
Function A calls Function B using the same arguments passed to A:

```
B(pkt=0x13a4bec0, off=, pktlen=0xe06d7363) Line 2506 + 0x21 bytes   C++
A(pkt=0x13a4bec0, off=0x00000034, pktlen=0x00000400) Line 1758  C++
```

"off" is missing and pktlen has a wrong value.

Can I trust this information?

Comment: If the dump belongs to a release build, probably not.

Comment: 0xe06d7363 is a magic number.  It is the exception code for a C++ exception.  Uncaught exceptions crash programs, hard to diagnose from the minidump.